# Simple Unity Grid Displays In Corrupted Fashion, Upon Camera Move, in Game View, Until Window Resized

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've recently migrated to the Universal Render Pipeline.

Here I have just the simplest scene. I am using an Orthographic camera. I have a prefab with a Sprite Renderer placed in the scene. The material is the Universal Render Pipeline/2D/Sprite-Unlit-Default material.

[image]

[image]

If I use the Inspector to adjust the tile position to the right, the tile smears in the game view. In the following I used the inspector to move the sprite to the right and then up.
[image]
Simply resizing the Game view, makes this smearing effect go away.

Why is this tile smearing in the game view? I did not see this before moving to the new rendering pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem seemed to be that the camera was in "Background Type" "Skybox", and this caused some problems with the Universal Rendering Pipeline. Not sure why this caused problems.. Perhaps I need to do something special with the skybox in the universal rendering pipeline.. However I dont want the sky box.. so I'm good for now.

As soon as I changed this to "Solid Color" the smearing issue went away.

[image]